# Disable textbox inside the update panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using the below code to `disable the textbox` inside the `update panel`. This is not working.

When i removed the update pannel its working fine. Kindly help me to disable the textbox inside the update pannel.

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Up_OnPayment" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_pay_amount" runat="server" Width="180px" CssClass="textorange"
                                                ClientIDMode="Static" autocomplete="off" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false"
                                                onkeypress="return validateOnlineAmount(event)"></asp:TextBox>
 </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
document.getElementById("txt_pay_amount").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Any Idea on this

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_disabled

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable it with `javascript`, you have to execute it `on load`.

Something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('#texboxid').disabled = true;
};
```

Or you can use

```
<input type = "Text" name = "name" id="1" disabled />
```